# How to iterate snapping input distance in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, snapping

Below is an image of my model. I want to run the snap between line features, then unsplit the lines (same as edit merge), then snap that output but at a greater distance threshold. I'm doing this iterative process because some of my line segments are small and get consumed by the snapping distance when I snap ends. However, the For Iterations tool wont point to the distance parameter. Maybe there's a smarter way to do this...

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you look at the help file for the [snap tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/editing/snap.htm#GUID-F32C87D7-08B6-407A-9CCD-E2AB6218ADE6) the parameter is a ValueTable, that's what it is expecting and the output of a FOR iterator will be just a number. You could use the calculate Value tool to build yourself a ValueTable and feed that into the snap tool. You will need to understand what inline variable substitution is, again in the Help file.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to light. I think I understand Inline Variable Sub, but I'm not sure how to make a Calculate Value script to get me value inputs for 1-5. Would that be an adjusted sequential number that stops at Nth number or a list? Would love an example because I'm no good at coding.

Comment: Again in the help file, all you needed to type in to help was valuetable, explore the code sample for [ValueTable](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/valuetable.htm#)